Help understanding Engineering diagram
My problem basically boils down to the fact that based on my reading of this diagram, N = G + H, but based on the table of dimensions, it is not true.
The diagram is from this document (OIML R 49-2 2013 edition, Annex I)
I have to turn this diagram into a 3D model, but I am unable to understand why N is not G + H and why the diagram is over-specified. I think I am making some rookie mistake in reading this diagram. Please help me out here.
Thanks in advance


I agree. The drawing is rather poor, specifically the chain dimension line for G and H is unclear, they should be offset vertically IMO. I would guess that N is supposed to be the overall length. As you say the drawing has redundant dimensions, one should be a ref.

N as the overall length adds up, once you add the 3.5 and 1.5 to G and H, you get exactly N for all sizes

Dimensions may all be reference for all we know; tolerances are not clear. It does appear that someone screwed up what N refers to.
